# Replace Js Variables names using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I search about protect my javascript code by changing his variable names (complicate the code lisibility like on [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js)).
i find [jasob application](http://www.jasob.com/) and i like it because it change maximum variables compared with other system like [jscompress](http://jscompress.com/)

i want to create php code that can transform maximum of varibles and put the compared in database to reverse action, it's seems to be very difficult to do.

Can someone know a existant code like this have proposition to simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> protect my javascript code

I don't think that is *practically possible*. JavaScript is rendered on Client-Side, so no matter you do security, the JS files still going to be downloaded on the client-machine.

Comment: yes sure, but i want to protect it like jquery code for exemple,juste by complicate the code lisibility

Comment: @chakrounyesser 99% of the time you want/need to encrypt/obfuscate javascript you're doing something wrong that should be done in the backend (where it can't be seen).

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes but this is also a practical system to discourage the hacker

Comment: @chakrounyesser Are you searching for [/packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)?

Comment: @chakrounyesser, Actually wrong. This will indeed increase the hacker's interest towards cracking your script, as they will be curious to know what you have packed inside the script.

Comment: yes i search for php code like packer, but packer dont modify all variables and i can't reverse action

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran hhhhhhh yes it's logic i think juste the pro hacker can really be interrested.